# Getting Value From A Third Table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
SELECT POSTS.* 
FROM POSTS 
LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIBERS 
ON POSTS.AUTHORID = SUBSCRIBERS.PROFILEID 
WHERE POSTS.AUTHORID = ? 
OR SUBSCRIBERS.SUBSCRIBERID = ? 
ORDER BY POSTID DESC 
LIMIT ?
```

The above is the query I'm using and this will select posts from the profiles a user is subscribed to. Now this works fine, but now I want to grab another column from another table.

In my third table USERS, I have an "AVATARID" which I want to access.

In my fetch loop for this query, it echos out the username of the post author, and the post body. What I want it to do is also echo out the avatarID of the user who wrote the post. I tried adding in another query inside my while loop, but I find that sloppy, and it also doesn't work :S

So, simple question: How do I access the AvatarID from the table USERS with the USERID of the AUTHORID from the post?

Comment: You just add another `inner join`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like...

```
SELECT POSTS.*, USERS.AVATARID
FROM POSTS 
LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIBERS ON POSTS.AUTHORID = SUBSCRIBERS.PROFILEID 
JOIN USERS ON POSTS.AUTHORID = USERS.USERID
WHERE POSTS.AUTHORID = ? 
OR SUBSCRIBERS.SUBSCRIBERID = ? 
ORDER BY POSTID DESC 
LIMIT ?
```

Comment: It's fine except it should be `INNER`, not `LEFT`

Comment: In addition I'd suggest specifying the fields you want from the POSTS table rather than using POSTS.*, however it's not going to stop the query working

Comment: Or an INNER JOIN if there must be an existing author for every post.

Comment: @zerkms Good point - the LEFT JOIN will produce the same result, but is unncessary.